# Socket based Android Application causes data connection to stall

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I'm developing an Android Application that utilises XMPP (aSmack Lib)

I've created some connection logic to close the connection after a certain amount of time. Anyone familiar with aSmack will know a disconnect can take some time and can cause the connection to lock on closing.

My connection method is handled by an Async task.

What I am finding is when testing, I upload the new app 10+ times in a night to my phone. After which it seems that the data connection (3G) has stalled and only turning off the data and back on can fix the issue.

The strange thing is, some services work such as facebook but others don't such as whatsapp

I initially thought it was because what's app uses XMPP and could have a socket or port conflict but since web won't work I'm stumped.

Has anyone come up against this problem before using Buffered readers/writers in Android?

What I need to check today when I get home is if the connection objects are being cleaned up properly when the application is killed and restarted.

Thanks